# Get all managed properties for search results javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, search-results

I'm following [this post](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-do-a-KeywordQuery-Search-using-Jquery-in-SharePoint-2013) on how to do a Keyword Query search in SP 2013. I'm getting the results items that I would expect. Now I need to display info about them.

The results are a mix of several different content types. They share some managed properties, but they also have some unique ones. The examples I've found show that I have to add each managed property I want to retrieve like so:

```
var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
var searchString = 'parentLink:"'+baseName+'"';
keywordQuery.set_queryText(searchString);

keywordQuery.set_sourceId(RESULTSOURCEGUID);

var properties = keywordQuery.get_selectProperties();
properties.add("Name");
properties.add("ContentType");
...and so on for each managed property name
```

But since I don't know what types will be in any given results how do I know which properties to request?

Is there a way to say "Give me all the managed properties associated with the returned item?"

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick for this.

You can add `managedproperties(filter=600/0/*)` as a **refiners** option to your query. Like this: `&refiners='managedproperties(filter%3d600%2f0%2f*)'`

Note that query should return at least one result. So you can use this query:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&rowlimit=1
&refiners='managedproperties(filter%3d600%2f0%2f*)'
&sourceid='[your source ID]'
```

**PrimaryQueryResult.RefinementResults.Refiners.Entries** will contain all fields, including managed. 
If you want to exclude default fields, grab all fields from first item of result: **PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows** and exclude them from **Refiners** list.

Comment: The original question from more than a year ago was for jsom and not REST api, but I have started using REST a lot more. I will have to check that out next time I need this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you add this to the display template, you will be able to see ALL the properties:

```
for (var p in ctx.CurrentItem) {
    console.log(p + ":" + $getItemValue(ctx, p)); 
}
```